# Binary expression in Lua

Tags: lua, bit-manipulation

Does Lua contain binary expressions like PHP? For example:

```
$v = 5;
for ($i=0; $i < $v; $i++) { 
    if($v & $i) {
        echo $i." ";
    }
}
```

Echo result:

```
1 3 4
```

If so, how to use them?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, really?

Answer (score 2):

Since version 5.2 Lua comes with bit32 library. `bit32.band` is equivalent to `&` operator in php. LuaJIT also has bit operations.

Edit

Well, they're not exactly equivalent, but serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

See Lua logical operators as described at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.3.